# Divisibility test using perhaps binomial thorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients, divisibility

I have to determine if $17^{21} + 19^{21}$ is divisible by any of the following numbers 
(a) 36 (b) 19 (c) 17 (d) 21.  I am trying to find using binomial expansion but getting stuck up with one or two terms - being not able to determine the divisibility.  Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For the first, note that if $n$ is odd then $x+y$ divides $x^n+y^n$.

Comment: @Andre!  that is great!  That fits the answer given in my book.  what is the proof of your statement for every odd n.  I can think of mathematical inductional proof!  Is there any other type of proof?  Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

First problem: There are many approaches. Since you mentioned the Binomial Theorem, let us first do it that way. We have
$$17^{21}=(18-1)^{21}=18^{21}-\binom{21}{1}18^{20}+\binom{21}{2}18^{19}-\binom{18}{3}18^{18}+\cdots -\binom{21}{21}18^0.$$
Similarly,
$$19^{21}=(18+1)^{21}=18^{21}+\binom{21}{1}18^{20}+\binom{21}{2}18^{19}+\binom{18}{3}18^{18}+\cdots +\binom{21}{21}18^0.$$
Add, and observe the cancellations. Each term that remains is divisible by $2\cdot 18$.

**Another way** to do it is to use the fact that for odd $n$ we have
$$x^n+y^n=(x+y)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2-\cdots +y^n.$$
A particular case if this identity may be familiar to you: $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$.

Take $x=17$, $y=19$, and $n=21$. We get that $17^{21}+19^{21}$ is equal to $(17+19$ times a complicated expression. We don't need to evaluate the expression to see that it is an integer.

**Still another way** to do it is to use congruences. We have $19\equiv -17\pmod{36}$. Thus
$$17^{21}+19^{21}\equiv 17^{21}+(-17)^{21}\equiv 17^{21}-17^{21}\equiv 0\pmod{36}.$$

**Remark:** The next two problems are not difficult. The last one is harder. The right tools to use depend on what number-theoretic tools are already available to you.

**Added**: The second and third problems are nearly identical. Suppose  that $19$ divides $17^{21}+19^{21}$. Since $19$ divides $19^{21}$, it follows that $19$ divides $17^{21}$. But if a prime divides a product, it divides at least one of the terms. So we conclude that $19$  divides $17$, which is false. It follows that $19$ cannot divide $17^{21}+19^{21}$.

For the last problem, we will show that $7$ does not divide our sum. It follows that $21$ cannot. We work modulo $7$.

By Fermat's Theorem we have $17^6\equiv 1\pmod{7}$. So $17^{18}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$ and therefore $17^{21}\equiv 17^3\equiv 3^3\pmod{7}$.

Similarly, $19^{21}\equiv 5^3\pmod{7}$. But $3^3+5^3=152\not\equiv 0\pmod{7}$.

Comment: You are right.  You make things so simple!  I don't see 'accept answer' option/item.  How do I accept the answer?  Can you also throw light on the divisibility by 17, 19 and 21?

Comment: I don't know about the accept process, have not yet asked a question. It cannot be hard, lots of people do it. As to the Question d) it would be useful, as I indicated, to know what tools you have. Congruences? Fermat "little" Theorem? Euler's Theorem and the Euler $\varphi$-function? For Questions b) and c) all you need is the fact that if a prime divides a product then it divides one of the terms. If you give some indication of your number theoretic knowledge, I can try to give an answer that is appropriate.

Comment: May be some minimum reputation required to accept answers!  I have accepted answers on the other stackexchanges.  I know number theory.  I know Chinese remiander theorem, congruences, Fermat's last theorem  etc.